# picamera mmalobj - Render last n seconds from Ringbuffer

Tags: camera, stream, raspberry-pi, render

Is there an easy way to playback video data stored in a stream-object (http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_streams.html) (e.g. a PiCameraCircularIO with h264 encoding) using one of the PiRenderers?

The mmalobj API (http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_mmalobj.html#id3) seems to support the playback of buffers, though it is hard to understand and everything I tried to use an MMALVideoDecoder and setting the input to a the data of a PiCameraCircularIO buffer failed.

I'm using the circular stream advancde recipe (http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#splitting-to-from-a-circular-stream) but rather than saving the last *n* seconds to a file, I want to playback them.